# Should I install morgan logger as dev dependency

Tags: node.js, morgan

should i install morgan as a normal `dependency` or as `devDependency` since I'm not gonna use the logging in **production** mode anyway:

```
if (config.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    app.use(morgan('dev', { stream: { write: message => logger.http(message) } }));
}
```

Comment: You could install it as a devDependency, but you are probably loading it via `require` above

Comment: YES, via `import`

Comment: Since you'll need it in 'prod', you have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `config.NODE_ENV` matches the `process.env.NODE_ENV` and that you installed via `npm install --production` or similar, then you don't need to include `morgan` in your `dependencies` and can just have it in `devDependencies`. You should move the `require` or `import` inside the if statement to prevent errors. When you call `require` or `import` is when it tries to load from `node_modules` or the module cache if it was already loaded.

```
if (config.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    app.use(morgan('dev', { stream: { write: message => logger.http(message) } }));
}
```

That said, I would personally include it in the `dependencies` and disable logging via a config setting in case I wanted to enable logging in my production environment to debug something.